# Where's Application Management in Sharepoint 2013 Online?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, anonymous-authentication

I've created a Publishing site using SharePoint 2013 Online, and want to allow anonymous users have access to the site.

My research on the internet has brought me to identical tutorials on how to do this, but I get stuck right at the beginning.

So the instructions follow as such:

> "Navigate to Application Management in SharePoint Central Administration and click on Manage web application."

But, after logging in to Sharepoint's Central Administration, I can't find the Application Management section!

Where is it? Do I need to activate some kind of Collection feature to have access to it?

Here's the link to one of the tutorials I tried following:

http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/226/Manage-Web-Application-permissions-in-SharePoint-2013

Thank you!
Nuno Vidal

Answer (score 0):

> "Anonymous access is ONLY available for public site hosted on
>   SharePoint (only one public site per Office 365 tenant)
>
> it's not possible to implement anonymous access on other SharePoint
>   sites (private) but you can invite external user (ie not Office 365
>   users)" - http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/5048.aspx

In a Public site you will see this:

http://community.office365.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/400x400/__key/communityserver-components-userfiles/00-00-13-40-40-Attached+Files/5226.1.png

Steps for activating on public site from [here](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/155/t/142924.aspx):

1. Navigate to the Office 365 admin center.
2. Click Sites on the top link bar.
3. Click Public site.
4. Click MAKE WEBSITE ONLINE at the top right corner of the page.

Comment: Thank you Robert! Does that mean that I can't allow anonymous user access to a Publishing site hosted in SharePoint 2013 Online?

Comment: Yes, you can only make anonymous users accessing a Public Site. But, you can Share sites with external users: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/share-a-site-with-external-users-HA102476183.aspx

Comment: Even if I just want to give anonymous users read access to the Publishing site? I'll give a look to the resource you shared. Thanks!

Comment: You can not do that, but look at the resources, they are quite alright

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Does it mean then that [this](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/10/15/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-a-sharepoint-2013-site/) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shyjumohan/anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2013/) articles are referring to Public sites? Or is it because these are for on premises SharePoint installations?

Comment: Both are for on premises! Please mark as an answer if this helped you