# Where's Application Management in Sharepoint 2013 Online - where is the answer please?

Tags: sharepoint-online

After some hours of google searching I eventually arrived on this site and found this thread:

[Where's Application Management in Sharepoint 2013 Online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74691/wheres-application-management-in-sharepoint-2013-online)

Regrettably whereas various users have marked the thread a "duplicate" neither I nor google nor this site's search engine appear to be able to find the original question and its solution.

Please may I humbly suggest that marking entries "duplicate" (as if an admonishment) devalues the support that I have heard about from stack exchange and to be positive please revise your protocol so as to include a link to the original solution - since clearly I cannot find it and my experience here is that you all know the answer but have no intention of telling anyone else - I know that is not the intention, but it is the effect. Exacting a penance in the form of having to search again is not an effective disciplinary tool: for myself, I only ask when all else has failed.

So, I will be very grateful if someone will please (I am practically begging here) tell me the solution or provide a link to it.

I do hope you can accept my post in the constructive manner in which I have sought, in difficult circumstances, to write it.

Regards,

Anthony

Answer (score 2):

Application Management Option is not available in SharePoint Online as this is only available on-prem Farm.

In order to Give Anonymous user access to your website, there are couple of options.

- try the codeplex solution http://anonymous365.codeplex.com/
- follow the instruction here to enable it http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2012/12/07/office-365-how-to-enable-anonymous-access-with-sharepoint-online.aspx
- also take look of this office blog. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232

Answer (score 1):

This isn't available in SharePoint Online.